# Resource error in xamarin studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
<style name="dialog_anim" >
<item name="android:widowEnterAnimation">@anim/Slide_up</item>
<item name="android:widowExitAnimation">@anim/Slide_right</item>
</style>
</resources>`
```

I have tried all possible answers from google none got correct so pls help me.

This is the error I'm getting:

> no resource found that matches android:windowEnterAnimation

Comment: no resource found that matches android:windowEnterAnimation is the error

Answer (score 1):

Typo, `windowEnterAnimation`, *not* `widowEnterAnimation`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
<style name="dialog_anim" >
<item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/Slide_up</item>
<item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/Slide_right</item>
</style>
</resources>
```